# Data restriction while consuming a SOAP based web service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, size, ibm-midrange

We are consuming a SOAP Web service from Java client. The service works fine with certain data and return Fault String with other set of data. Fault String is "Received SOAP request with no data" The exception stack trace does not say much as to identify the root cause. We are thinking that it is the amount of data that we are sending to the service is causing the trouble but if we use SoapUI to call the service with the same data it works. What could be the possible reason to receive a fault string with one method and not the other? Do we need to set some parameters in our Java client that can enable to us consume the web service with large amount of data. We are running the java client on jvm running on AS400 system.

Note: by large we do not mean MBs.

Comment: You should use a debug proxy server to monitor the exact communication between your application and the SOAP server. E.g. in Eclipse there is a Tool named "TCP/IP Monitor". Configuration is under Preferences/Run/Debug/TCP/IP-Monitor. Then add the view Debug/TCP/IP-Monitor.

Comment: The IBM i as client uses EBCDIC character encoding. Is possible, that whatever unstated [or at least I do not see any mention of what] method is being used in the failing case has failed to compose the SOAP request in UTF8, and therefore ends up passing some EBCDIC data, whereas when using the SoapUI, that particular processing is always ensuring the proper conversion.?